# How can I work with .iloc[] in Python to do some calculation?

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, vector, calculation

I have to implement some functions to calculate special values. I read a csv file for it with pd.read_csv(). Then I used .iloc[] to find the respective row and column I need for my calculation:

V_left = data_one.iloc[0,0:4]

V_right= data_one.iloc[0,5:9]

My formula, which I want to implement is: V_left/V_right

V is a vector of 5 parameters (values).

My question is now: How can I use the values, which I pick out with .iloc[], to do a calculation like my formula?

[See me current code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsRAS.png)

[image]

Comment: post some sample input and output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`V_left.values` and `V_right.values` to make those dataframes numpy arrays, so that you can manipulate them. 
However, I wouldn't use iloc in the first place, you can directly convert them:

```
V_left = data_one.values[0,:4]
V_right = data_one.values[0, 5:9]
```

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Thank you.

Comment: Another problem is that I am missing the 1st and 6th values in the output (when I print out V_left and V_right). That's strange.

Comment: do you have headers in your csv file? If not you should set your header to none while reading it: `read.csv('path/to/file', header=None)`. 
Then, maybe check your indexing. Best!

Comment: You can see my csv file in my question.

Comment: I don't know how to solve this problem, that the first and 6th value is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `V_left.values / V_right.values` should be enough.